# Cannot activate virtual environment on Linux (Docker Quickstart Terminal virtual machine)

Tags: python, linux, docker, virtualenv

I am making some experiments with docker, using the Docker Quickstart Terminal virtual machine, on Windows 10 home.

I am following the steps listed in [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-python-virtual-environment-windows-linux/) to create a virtual environment.

I manage to create the environment, but then I cannot activate it.

Creating the virtual environment:

```
Tommaso@N552VW-Tommaso MINGW64 ~/Django rest framework/Udemy Django/TDD-Python-Django/recipe-app-api (main)

$ virtualenv met6

Using base prefix 'c:\\applicazioni_tommaso\\phyton'
New python executable in C:\Users\Tommaso\DJANGO~1\UDEMYD~1\TDD-PY~1\RECIPE~1\met6\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

Activating the virtual environment

```
Tommaso@N552VW-Tommaso MINGW64 ~/Django rest framework/Udemy Django/TDD-Python-Django/recipe-app-api (main)

$ source met6/bin/activate

bash: met6/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

Why does not it find the virtual environment I just created? I am following the tutorial step by step, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `source $(pwd)/met6/bin/activate`
mingw has some problems with whitespaces in directorys as far as i know, possible rename the directorys before trying it 'Django rest framework'

Comment: It does not work, I also tryed to add " at the beginning and at the end of the pwd string.